# A lighter GRAILS without GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am building a middleware with GRAILS. It will expose a unified range of REST services hiding a number of backend systems.

I will access all the backends through REST. I do not need any database, in this middleware application. How can I remove from the framework the Hibernate. What else I could remove in order to have a lighter deploy-able system ?

Comment: I think its a good fit for [grails (version 3) profile](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#profiles) - you can check for existing profiles on [github](https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/tree/master/profiles)

Comment: hibernate alone is a plugin and can be added/removed with ease. GORM is a more general beast, and is now an integral part of Grails

Comment: after taking away enough you might end up with springboot+groovy or ratpack...

Comment: My vote for this kind of middleware would be: Ratpack.

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

As Frederic Henri said, take a look at Grails 3 profiles. If that's still too heavy of a stack, Grails is probably not the best choice for you.

If you want to stick with Groovy, *(heck who wouldn't)* then take a look at [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/).